# SSLV3 Handshake issue after Poodle vulnerability fix

Tags: java, https, handshake, sslv3

I recently applied the patch for POODLE vulnerability on my server and tested for its vulnerability and things looked pretty good. But the problem now is that I have an internal service that communicated via HTTPS and that communication is breaking with the following error -

Both the services are deployed in the same tomcat server - hence it's an internal web service call.

How can I fix this?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$3.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:312)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:812)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:543)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
```